# Connecting earphones to desktop for audio does not work

Tags: windows-7, audio, desktop-computer, microphone, speakers

I need to use my earphones as a mic on my pc (which has separate input and output jacks), but if I connect my earphones to the audio input **only**, it uses the earphone's output as input. If I use a y-splitter, the desktop correctly uses the earphone's mic as a mic. However, the wire is too short to reach my ears in this case. How can I solve this?